# Vimeo Oauth: This app can only upload to the app owner's account

Tags: oauth, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm setting up the Vimeo Oauth flow so that others can upload videos to their own accounts.
I successfully go through the Oauth flow for my own account, however others get the
'**This app cannot generate a token with the upload scope for the requested account. This app can only upload to the app owner's account.**' error upon the redirection to Vimeo.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To enable others to upload videos to their OWN accounts -
you should **not only set up the Oauth flow**,
you should also **join the Vimeo Partner Network**.

You can join the Vimeo Partner Network by

1. [contacting Vimeo support](https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042881671-Upload-access-), or by
2. [filling out the form](https://developer.vimeo.com/apps).